Maintaining prefix argument sensitivity: wrapping functions in emacs minor mode menus
I have a set of functions, some of which accept a prefix argument:
(defun prefix-arg-test (&optional prefix)
  (interactive "P")
  (if prefix
      (message "prefix")
    (message "no-prefix")))

While others work without one:
(defun always-no-prefix-arg-test ()
  (interactive)
  (message "always-no-prefix"))

Due to an issue (bug? Unwanted Focus Shift when Clicking Menu Functions in Emacs Mode Line), I need to ignore mouse events when calling these functions from the menu of a minor mode.
For this purpose, I've written this macro:
(defmacro with-ignore-mouse-events (&rest body)
  "Ignore mouse events before evaluating BODY."
  `(progn
     (when (input-pending-p)
       (let ((event (read-event)))
         (if (mouse-event-p event)
             (let ((button (event-basic-type event)))
               (if (eq button 'mouse-1)
                   (ignore)
                 (setq unread-command-events (list event))))
           (setq unread-command-events (list event)))))
     ,@body))

To call a function wrapped with this macro, I've written this function:
(defun call-wime (func)
  "Call FUNC wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro."
  (with-ignore-mouse-events (funcall func)))

Now, I'd like to use easy-menu-define to call my functions from the menu of the minor mode while wrapping them with my macro. I've tried something like this:
(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " MWE "
  :keymap `((,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . prefix-arg-test))
  (if mwe-mode
      (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
        "MWE"
        '("MWE mode"
          ["prefix-arg-test" prefix-arg-test t]
          ["prefix-arg-test wrapped" (call-wime 'prefix-arg-test) t]
      ["always-no-prefix-arg-test" (call-wime 'always-no-prefix-arg-test) t]))
    t))

However, the issue is that the wrapped functions no longer respond to the prefix argument.
In the provided example, when I click on "prefix-arg-test" in the menu, the function retains sensitivity to the prefix argument. However, if I click on "prefix-arg-test wrapped", the prefix argument is ignored.
How can I wrap my functions (only when called with the mouse from the menu of my minor mode) while still maintaining their sensitivity to the prefix argument?
An ideal solution would not differentiate between functions that expect and those that don't expect the use of a prefix argument.

I solved using this code:
(defun call-wime (func &optional use-prefix-arg)
  "Call FUNC wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro.
In USE-PREFIX-ARG is non-nil pass `current-prefix-arg' to FUNC."
  (if use-prefix-arg
      (with-ignore-mouse-events (funcall func current-prefix-arg))
    (with-ignore-mouse-events (funcall func))))

(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " MWE "
  :keymap `((,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . prefix-arg-test))
  (if mwe-mode
      (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
        "MWE"
        '("MWE mode"
          ["prefix-arg-test wrapped" (call-wime 'prefix-arg-test t) t]
          ["always-no-prefix-arg-test" (call-wime 'always-no-prefix-arg-test) t]))
    t))

I simply added an optional argumento to the call-wime function so I can pass
current-prefix-arg to the functions that need it.
